# more than 2 model in same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the examples above, i use a button to close the modal. However, with a little bit of JavaScript, you can also close the modal when clicking outside of the modal box.

the problem is when i use 2 modals just i can close first modal when i click any where , the second one i cannot !!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>


  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal 1</button>
  
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal 2</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>model 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>model 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01','id02');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `document.getElementById`, just like the `Element` in the name indicates, only gets one element, so the second parameter, `'id2'`, is ignored, and you end up only getting the first modal element. [Read more in the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

You can use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to fix this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>


  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal 1</button>
  
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal 2</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>model 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>model 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script>
// Get the modal
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('w3-modal');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
console.log(event.target, event.target == modals[0], event.target == modals[1]);
    if (event.target == modals[0] || event.target == modals[1]) {
        modals[0].style.display = "none";
        modals[1].style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Optionally, you can use a relatively new api, [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), to unify the usages of selecting DOM elements. It uses css selector like string to select elements. *But it's a bit new so you may want to check browser compatibility before using it*.

Comment: its done , realy appreciate that .. thank a lot my friend .